# Using Raspberry Pi as a Wi-Fi Scanner/Analyser

Tags: wifi, monitoring

I'm working on an indoor geo-location topic and I'm a newbie with RPi.

I want the RPi to scan Wi-Fi devices (and get their IP addresses) and determine their emission power. I want to associate each IP address with its received power by means of RPi.

Is it possible? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm newbie with RPi, and I don't know from where to start

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network!  I have suggested an edit to the title and tags to more accurately reflect the body of the question... By the way if you are scanning for devices, if there is more than one WiFi network present and they are using IPv4 addresses (most will) and Network Address Translation or other systems where the devices are using a private range of IP address (e.g. 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x) then the IP address is less useful than the MAC ([Media Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)) as that WILL be a unique ID.

Comment: I'm using only one WIFI and I need IP/MAC addresses combined for each device: scanning the IP address to get different information and then the MAC represents a unique identifier that will be stored in a server. 
Is there a way to combine them ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, a great tutorial is [Wi-Fi on the Command Line](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/wi-fi-command-line), but make sure to use an 8dBi, or *greater*, omni-direcional/uni-directional antenna with your Wi-Fi card. Feel free to ask further questions - I'll be glad to answer.

UPD - as requested - a *cite* with a main concept :

> ```
> sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
> ```
>
> You'll see output resembling:
>
> ```
> Cell 01 - Address: 00:11:22:33:44:55
>       ESSID:"network-essid"
>       Mode:Master
>       Channel:11
>       Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
>       Quality=100/100  Signal level:-47dBm  Noise level=-100dBm
>       Encryption key:off
>       .
>       .
> ```

Comment: While your answer does point to a tutorial which may answer the question, there isn't enough detail *in your answer*. Should the tutorial vanish, the answer will be useless. Can you summarise the important points?

Comment: I want to use RPi as an access point which collect the needed information (ip adresses and received power).
Is it possible to use wifi P2P ?

Comment: @goobering I'm not citing the manual/google/standard - the main point is to use iwXXX - especially **iwconfig** and **iwlist** tools to probe an environment step-by-step. The notice about an antenna is from my own personal experience measuring WiFi and BT signals.

Comment: @CyrineNasri yes it's possible. It depends on your hardware which tactics will succeed : probing or enabling/adding a debug output from a wifi driver, please tell me your desired setup and HW specs - I may be able to help you

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin - If you could update/expand your answer with the information in your comment that would be great... that is the point that goobering is trying to make. As he said, if the link goes down, then your answer, as it currently stands, will not be much use. So, if you can edit your answer (and not add extra information as comments, as it makes the answer somewhat piecemeal) and cite the main points from the article, then it would make your answer much more useful. Thanks.

Comment: @CyrineNasri then try this dongle I'm using myself TP-LINK [TL-wn722nc](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-11_TL-WN722NC.html) an external antenna jack is what you need and even a standart antenna shipped with it is good for a start.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the tutorial it really helps ! But I want to know if the "iwconfig" command is used in access point or I can run it in my RPi ? I don't understand why I need antenne ?

Comment: @CyrineNasri You should run it in your RPi to *list the AP's/signal sources your device can see* and to read it's signal strength/power metrics e.t.c. Why do you need an antenna - it's simple. WiFi equpiment needs and has an antennas **ALWAYS** : there's no receiver and/or transmitter that works without it. It can be built-in or replaceable externally attached one. The better antenna you have, the more signal sources you can receive(you will be able to determine weak ones from noise) and - for your task - the more precisely you can see the signal power.

Comment: Ah ok ! And do I need an antenna for each RPi (my architecture consists of 3 RPi). Could you please guide me to the right tutorial to configure the antennas ?

Comment: Is there any equivalent command to iwspy?

Comment: @CyrineNasri there are different implementations of `iwspy`, of course, but I do recommend you to start with iwspy itself, it's more than enough. Antennas - for all your navigation analyzers, of course, and the same ones - to simplify the calculations. To pick an antennas for you I recommend you to start with a 5dBi ones, they're shipped with the cards I've linked. After testing PoC - buy a 8dBi ones omni-directional and apply to the RPi's, then calibrate with greater precision

Comment: the problem with iwspy is that it shows me error as follows: wlan0 Inteface doesn't support wireless statics collection. I can't replace it with iwconfig, because this one gives information about AP only !

Comment: try `wavemon` it provides information about the Parameters of the WiFi signal you are connected to if you want to work with __LQI or RSSI__ values. It is available on GitHub